# Preventing UI from freezing while processing data

Tags: c#, java, android, multithreading, xamarin.android

I am having some problems with BluetoothChat (that I beleive its the same code on bot Java and MonoForAndroid) example app. I have connected my Android to an microcontroller using a Bluetooth module. In case of sending messages (just raw bytes to microcontroller) it works just fine!

The microcontroller streams a constant serial message and I want to read that data. There is a class named `MyHandler` in [BluetoothChat.cs](http://pastebin.com/4WtyQFjN) app that has a code block like this:

```
    case MESSAGE_READ:
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.Obj;
        // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
        var readMessage = new Java.Lang.String (readBuf, 0, msg.Arg1);
        bluetoothChat.conversationArrayAdapter.Add(
        bluetoothChat.connectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);
        break;
```

So what I need to do is to process the incoming raw data and then change color of some buttons, So I made the follwing changes to the code above:

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.Obj;

         //I have just added this code and it blocks the UI
         bluetoothChat.ProcessIncomingData(readBuff);

    break;
```

And in the `BluetootChat` activity I have this method:

```
    public void ProcessIncomingData(byte[] readBuf)
    {

        if (_logBox != null)
        {
            _logBox.Text += "\r\n"; //TextView

            foreach (var b in readBuf)
            {
                _logBox.Text += (uint)b + " "; //Show the bytes as int value
            }
        }
    }
```

`

But  unfortunately the changes I made stops the UI and the app crashes after f short while.

Any ideas how can I do this neatly without freezing the UI?

Comment: AsyncTask or Thread/Handler.

Comment: This seems odd... a serial read buffer shouldn't have enough data in it to make your `foreach` loop even break a sweat unless you're doing more than just posting the characters to a text box. It especially shouldn't cause a crash.  Do you have any more debug information?  How big are your `readBuf` arrays and how often do they come in?  I mean, bluetooth just can't supply data that quickly.  Something else must be going on.

Comment: @J...

Well I guess since the microcontroller is streaming data quite fast (I beleive every 15ms) that can be the cause of UI lock and crash after a while (the crash doesn happen at fixed times sometimes it just does not crash)

Comment: How much data every 15ms?  That's really a rather large amount of time.  If the stream is constant then it won't matter if you do it in a thread or in the handler - whatever processing needs to happen in less time than the interval or you will clog your buffers until they overflow.  If the handler is firing every 15ms then you do not need a thread.  Is the above your real code or are you doing something else besides `_logBox.Text += (uint)b+"";`?

Comment: @J... Well I finally solved the problem with intense threading! Thanks for joining in anyways!

Comment: I would suggest _not_ using `_logBox.Text += ...`, _especially_ within a loop, as this will require _lots_ of temporary string instances + marshaling == blech. Instead, assuming `_logBox` is an `EditText`, use [TextView.Append(string)](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.TextView.Append(System.String)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to hand the work off to a background thread in order to keep the UI thread free to respond to input. I wrote up a post awhile back outlining some of the different methods available to you for doing background threads: [Using Background Threads in Mono For Android Applications](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/)

One thing to be careful with when dealing with background threads is that if you want to make any changes to the UI, you must switch back to the UI thread. You can do this by using the `RunOnUiThread()` method.

Comment: Did you look at his code?  There's no work for a thread to do.  He's pumping bytes into a textbox - it shouldn't be causing the UI thread to block for any significant duration, nor the app to crash.

Comment: @Greg I tried to do it using `QueueUSerWorkITems` and also tried `RunOnUiThread` but I still get the same UI freeze. Maybe the constant inputs that I get from bluetooth makes this? (The micro sends some byte series at fixed 15ms intervals)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new thread for the process to take place in.

```
public static void threadProcess()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                // Process that will run in the thread
                }
            };
            thread.start();
}
```